# A Section in My HTML is having a problem with its position

Tags: html, css

I have a site and it has 2 sections. the left section is a navigation bar with menus below.
The section next to it is the main section or where the website content must be placed. My problem is the right section is positioned a few pixels from the header. How can i fix this? I provided some image to let you see how the website should look like.

```css
          /*WRITTEN USING SASS*/
    #side-menu{
    margin-top: 25px;

 .side-menu-bg {
  width: max-content;
   h3 {
    position: absolute;
       color: white;
       padding: 0px 18px;
        font-size: 27px;
   }
   img {
       display: -webkit-box;
   }
 }
 .side-nav-bar {
         width: 210px;
      position: unset;
      margin-top: -3px;
      display: inline-flex;
      z-index: 1;
      flex-direction: column;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: #ffffff;
   a {
       display: inherit;
       color: #707070;
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 15px;
       padding: 10px 18px;
       position: relative;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8; 
   }
   .active-link{
    color: #a40022;
       border-bottom: 2px solid #8a001c;
   }
 }

 .right-contents {
  float: right;
   .title h3 {
    font-size: 38px;
   }
   .body-content {
      background-color: #d3d3d3;
      height: 1094px;
      width: 738px;
 }
}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> <!--to make contents center-->
  <div id="side-menu">
   <div class="side-menu-bg">
    <h3>KU 스타트업</h3>
    <img src="images/bg/bg_03.png">
   </div>
   <div class="side-nav-bar">
    <a href="#" class="active-link">인사말</a>
    <a href="#">창업 비전</a>
    <a href="#">창업 프로세스</a>
    <a href="#">창업부서소개</a>
    <a href="#">찾아오시는 길</a>
   </div>
    <div class="right-contents">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>인사말</h3>
       <div class="body-content">
        sample text
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[image: space above the h3 content]

[image: expected output]

Comment: do you  have any link to this site??

Comment: If you have a link to this website then share, since its difficult to tell the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0` to your `h3` tag.. h3 has `margin-to` and `margin-bottom` by default. thanks

```
.right-contents {
float: right;
    .title h3 {
        font-size: 38px;
        margin: 0; /*add this*/
    }
    .body-content {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    height: 1094px;
    width: 738px;
```

}

Comment: it did not work when i tried to make the margin: 0 in my .right-contents class @Xenio Gracias

Comment: add it to h3 which is inside .right-contents. I have updated my answer. please check. thanks

Comment: the entire section did not make a change still. it's only the empty div and the h3 adjusted with each other

Comment: https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/MLjgzm?editors=1100 .. Check this link and tell me what is the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
/*WRITTEN USING SASS*/
#side-menu{
margin-top: 25px;

.side-menu-bg {
    width: max-content;
        h3 {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
            padding: 0px 18px;
            font-size: 27px;
        }
        img {
            display: -webkit-box;
        }
}
.side-nav-bar {
        width: 210px;
        position: unset;
        margin-top: -3px;
        display: inline-flex;
        z-index: 1;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
  }
a {
            display: inherit;
            color: #707070;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 10px 18px;
            position: relative;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;   
        }
        .active-link{
            color: #a40022;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #8a001c;
        }
}

.right-contents {
   width: 65%;
   margin-top: -3px;
    display: inline-flex;
        .title h3 {
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        .body-content {
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
        height: 1094px;
        width: 738px;
}
</style>
```